# Calling a method with no name

Tags: c++

I have this line that I need to be able to run with the code I am writing:

```
 euro(2, Regular)
```

`euro` is an object from a class named `MainControl`, and I have an enum defined:

```
enum VoterType { All, Regular, Judge };
```

Basically I understand that we want to use some method from the class named `MainControl`, but I don't see the name of the method that should be used?

Given the fact that this function returns `void`, how exactly is the declaration supposed to look like in the class `MainControl`?

Comment: Are you looking for a _function-call operator_: something as `MainControl::operator()(int, VoterType) { ... }`?

Comment: I think we need to see the code of `MainControl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MainControl` class is implementing a custom [overloaded operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), i.e., *"function call operator"*.

> How exactly is the declaration supposed to look like in the class MainControl?

The method signature should be something similar to:

```
class MainControl {
  // ...
 public:
  void operator()(int, VoterType);
};
```

---

> When a user-defined class overloads the function call operator, operator(), it becomes a FunctionObject type.

In short, your class instance (`euro`) is a *FunctionObject* and that particular method can be simply invoked as (for example):

```
euro(2, VoterType::Regular)
```

---

**Additional Notes**

Just for sake of completeness, the "operator-method" is just like another method (no black magic here).

Indeed, you can even invoke it with the complete name:

```
euro.operator()(2, VoterType::Regular);
```

But the syntax becomes pretty ugly.